# Can I generate an image result from ZedGraph?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, zedgraph

I am trying to use ZedGraph from MVC. Can I just generate an image result from ZedGraph and reference it from my view?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I figured out how:

```
public FileContentResult Graph()
{
    var web = new ZedGraphWeb();
    web.Height = 450;
    web.Width = 800;
    web.RenderGraph += (w, g, masterPane) =>
                       {
                           GraphPane myPane = masterPane[0];
                           var xData = new double[] { 1, 2, 3 };
                           var yData = new double[] { 10, 60, 50 };
                           myPane.AddCurve("Allocated", xData, yData, Color.Black);
                       };
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    web.CreateGraph(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    return new FileContentResult(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
}

<img src="@Url.Action("Graph")"/>
```

ZedGraph can be used from Windows Forms and as an ASP.NET web control. Using it from MVC is harder and this image method is the approach I came up with. Using ASP.NET web controls is possible in MVC, I think (does anyone know how?). If you have any other suggestions, please post them.

Answer (score 0):

Another [example](http://blog.denouter.net/2012/03/zedgraph-in-mvc3.html) of how to do it.